# Blocking Coalitions

Tags: microeconomics, self-study, general-equilibrium, pareto-efficiency, walrasian

For $n$ individuals, can a blocking coalition only be formed by at least $n/2$ individuals? For example, if there are 6 individuals, can less than 3 individuals form blocking coalitions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coalition formation is not the same as majority voting. Say, in a single good economy, individual 1 has the entire endowment, so $\mathbf e=(1,0,0,0,0,0)$. Then individual 1 forms a blocking coalition to any allocation $\mathbf x=(x_1,\dots,x_6)$ where $x_1<1$.